# Choosing the "visible column selector" mechanism for a grid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, header

I'm facing such problem: there's a need to select a mechanism, allowing user to hide/show columns in a DataGrid.

One of suggested ways is adding a button (which looks like a column header, but with no column). When user clicks on it, the list of columns comes and user may select columns to hide/show. But is there any way to have such column in a grid (just a header with no column as example - you may see the grid in Mozilla Thunderbird)?

The other, less likely way, was the popup list, appearing when mouse hover the DataGrid. But this list would be used rarely. So, this flashing list would be just a headache for an end-user.

The ways with mouse-clicking. I'm just afraid, that they would be left unnoticed and user would have a hard days while using a grids with a dozens columns.

Any thoughts about that? Is there any way to achieve the 1st way, or maybe there's a better approach to solve this problem?

Maybe it would be better if I just provide a pic of this magical "header with no column", to escape confusion.

There's a clickable column-header in a grid, but there's no column under it.

There's some area right above scrollbar in the dataGrid, it might be the right place for putting this functionality. But it seems like I can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe combined approach - some (small) x-shaped button in the header to hide column, and popup list (invoked somehow) to restore it. Header with no column... It's strange and if there's many of them, it's stranger yet.

Edit: you need custom header item renderer. If it renders last header (should be able to determine that with 'owner' property and column info), it shows button for column selection. Otherwise, it shows button to hide column.

Comment: I've provided some details to make it more clear ..
> invoked somehow
that's what I'm looking for .. mystery "Somehow")

>if there's many of them
No-no .. just 1 .. I hope that the picture would remove this misunderstanding ..

Comment: It can be created just over datagrid control. Of course, it will occlude part of the header, so header must be tuned for that. Not very clean solution, but simple (if you can deal with header).

Comment: Or make it part of last header (you have to change header anyway).

Comment: Sorry for a late response .. the problem seem to be postponed. But it also seems like I really wouldn't escape this "customizing renderers" thingy. Thanks for your help, I'll try to not forget to post the solution in the end of all that :)